# Uniformly convergent implies bounded domain

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, boundary-value-problem

Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ and $f_{n}$ a function with $f_{n}:A \to \mathbb R; x\to\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}$.

Now I tried to prove that if $f_{n}$ uniformly converges, $A$ is bounded. I tried to find a subsequence that converges. From that it follows that A is bounded. I’m not sure if it will follow for every sequence of functions in A.

The other implication isn’t correct I thought but I can’t find a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $(f_n)$ converges uniformly if and only if $A$ is bounded.

First note that if $x \in A$ then  $|\frac {x+1} n |<\frac 1 2$ for $n$ sufficiently large so $f_n \to 0$ point-wise.

If $A$ is bounded then $\sup_{x \in A} |\frac {x+1} n |<\frac 1 2$ for $n$ sufficiently large so $f_n \to 0$ uniformly.

Now suppose $f_n \to 0$ uniformly. Then $\sup _{x \in A} |\frac {x+1} n |^{n}<1 $ for $n$ sufficiently large. This gives $|x+1| <n^{1/n}$ for all $x \in A$. Since $n^{1/n}$ tends to $1$ it is bounded. Hence $\sup_{x \in A} |x+1| <\infty$ which implies $\sup_{x \in A} |x| <\infty$. Thus $A$ is bounded.

**Answer for the edited version**: If $|x| >1$ then $|f_n(x)|>|x|^{n} |\frac x {|x|}+\frac 1 {n|x|}|^{n} \to \infty$. Hence, (uniform) convergence on $A$ implies that $|x| \leq 1$ for all $x \in A$ which proves that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: I’m sorry someone changed my question wrong it’s x+1/N and not (x+1)/n

Comment: @mathmath I have edited my answer.

Comment: when you prove that A is bounded? Why you still use (x+1)/n?

Comment: @mathmath There was  a typo. I have corrected it. Note that $(1\pm \frac1 {n|x|})^{n} \to e^{\pm 1/|x|} >0$ and $|x|^{n}  \to \infty$ so the product tends to $\infty$.

Comment: i don't see the correction you still say that sup|(x+1)/n|...

Comment: @mathmath Are you reading the last part of my answer or the first part? $(x+\frac  1 n)^{n}=x^{n} (1+\frac  1 {nx})^{n}$ for $x >1$. Do you agree with this?

Comment: first part, i see the edited version now i think you forgot it

Comment: i don't get it, sorry